# Accessing AWS credentials on Windows 10 WSL : Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 169.254.169.254:80 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, credentials

I want to access my AWS credentials that I saved in C:/Users/myusername/.aws
The file is called credentials without any extension and it has my aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key and aws_session_token

The code below does not work on windows 10 WSL,producing error : Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 169.254.169.254:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1121:14)

The code works on ubuntu, with the credentials saved in .aws folder in the home directory.

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

AWS.config.getCredentials(function (err) {

if (err) console.log(err.stack);
  // credentials not loaded
else {
  console.log("Access key:", AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId);
  console.log("Secret access key:", AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey);
}
```

});

Comment: I would guess it has something to do with the fact that in WSL, the `C:\ ` drive is found under `/mnt/c/` and the environment variable `AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE` has to be set accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I use wsl terminal in visual code. How should I set the AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE and where should I place it?

Comment: Have you tried creating a symlink? `ln -s /mnt/c/Users/myusername/.aws ~/.aws` from inside wsl might do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running WSL, the `C:\` drive is mounted in `/mnt/`.
To use the `crendentials` file stored in the Windows path `C:\Users\myusername\.aws\`,
you have two options:

## 1. Using an environment variable

The environment variable `AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE` has to be set to the path of the `credentials` file.

In WSL:

```
> export AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE="/mnt/c/Users/myusername/.aws/credentials"
```

## 2. Using a symlink

(Thanks to @Michael-sqlbot)

In WSL:

```
> ln -s /mnt/c/Users/myusername/.aws ~/.aws
```

---

Now, your Node.js application should be able to access the credentials.